# send argument of link to another link asp net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a default page with a gridview showing different categories.
When I enter a category, the name of the category is passed as an argument in the link, like

```
http://localhost:49442/category.aspx?category=Windows
```

I have a link with  in there for a "New topic". I want to send the "category" parameter further.
I tried an approach but with no results.

The code is

```
<a id="topicLink" href="default.aspx">New Topic</a>
```

And the code in C# is

```
string x = Request.QueryString["category"];
topicLink.Href = "newtopic.aspx?category=" + x;
```

> Error: the name topicLink does not exist in this context

How can I do this ?

Comment: are you using WebForms or MVC? from your code Im suspecting Webforms. Also, your link is it an asp control or html?

Comment: Are you using any model in your view? If so you can pass this parameter as a property of that model and concat it in the view.

Comment: i don't use any model, it's very basic, my link is html

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: "the name topicLink does not exist in this context"

Comment: Simply add `runat="server"` in your html code and then you will be able to use topicLink. Posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `runat="server"` in your html code like this:

```
<a id="topicLink" runat="server" href="default.aspx">
New Topic
</a>
```

Then you can use `topicLink` to change the `href` value just as you did. :)

Answer (score 1):

ok,  you want to use something like this when the event fires

```
$("#bttnId").click(function() {
   $("a").attr("href", "your url here")
})
```

this code is based on a click event, in this instance its a button, but if its coming from a page load event from parameters you might want to take a look at purl.js which is a third party js file that will allow you to grab the parameters from a query string and then you can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = $.url().param('category');
  $("a").attr("href", url)
})
```

you can get more information about purl from here  https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

please also note this is pseudo code and should be enough to give you a direction of where you want to go

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `HyperLink` Control

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="default.aspx">New Topic</asp:HyperLink>
```

You can then alter the `NavigateUrl` property in code behind.

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl += "?category=" + x;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to create the hyperlink from the begin with the right URL

```
<a id="topicLink" href="default.aspx?category="+<%Request.QueryString["category"]%>New Topic</a>
```

Comment: At least write it correctly: `<a href="default.aspx?category=<%=Request.QueryString["category"]%>">New Topic</a>`